# Not able to install any packages on my Linux test server

Tags: python, package

Could you please help me? I'm not able to install the below package or any other packages.

```
obevt021:~ # pip install paramiko
Collecting paramiko
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/paramiko/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/paramiko/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/paramiko/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/paramiko/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/paramiko/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement paramiko (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for paramiko
```

Comment: pip gives a connection error if you are connected to internet via proxy server. if you are you have to use ```-p``` at the end of the command followed by your proxy server address

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your pip with the following:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```